# How to un-retweet a retweeted tweet with twitteroauth?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I use abrahams/twitteroauth (php), twitter api 1.1. I can not find suitable method for give up from retweeted tweet.

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`POST` statuses/destroy/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/destroy/:id) to undo retweets -- retweets are just special kinds of tweets. By specifying the ID of the retweet (as opposed to the tweet that was retweeted) you can delete the retweet on behalf of the current user.

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16618

Hope this helps!